# Create a folder in any user's Desktop directory if it does not exist

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, create-directory

I have a file which, among other things, opens a specific folder when a button is pressed. I will be distributing this file to other users so the code must know to look at the correct directory to:

1. See if the folder exists already or not, and if it exists open the folder
2. Create the folder if it does not already exist, and open it after creating

So far, here is the pertinent section of my code:

```
If Dir("C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\sampleFolder", vbDirectory) = "" Then
          MkDir "C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\sampleFolder"
          retVal = Shell("explorer.exe C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\sampleFolder", vbNormalFocus)
     Else
          retVal = Shell("explorer.exe C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\sampleFolder", vbNormalFocus)
End If
```

My main issue is that I can't figure out how to get a user's actual username that would appear in the file path "C:\Users__________\Desktop"

Is this even the right methodology? The code works if I insert my own username into the code, but I can't figure out the way to get the username automatically so the code is easy on the end user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Public Sub EnsureDesktopFolderExists(ByVal folderName As String)
    Dim path As String
    path = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & folderName
    If Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir path
End Sub
```

[VBA Environ](http://codevba.com/office/environ.htm#.V7t1zzWMFxI)

Answer (score 1):

> My main issue is that I can't figure out how to get a user's actual username that would appear in the file path "C:\Users__________\Desktop"

Generally, the `Environ` function should work (although there are probably exceptions), and you can condense the code a bit, too:

```
Dim username$
Dim myFolder$
username = ENVIRON("username")
myFolder = "C:\Users\" & username & "\Desktop\sampleFolder"

If Dir(myFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
     MkDir myFolder
End If

retVal = Shell("explorer.exe " & myFolder, vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: Why the `$` at the end of your variables during declaration? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @kyle  Shorthand for `As String` :)

Comment: ++ nice, @Kyle see [Declaring Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables#t=20160822220156988865)

Comment: `Environ` returns a `Variant`, which incurs implicit conversion when assigning the string variable, so the string-returning `Environ$` function should be preferred. Also hard-coding `C:\Users\` isn't a good idea (what if OS is installed on a D: drive?). See [Om3r's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39089389/1188513) which uses the `USERPROFILE` variable, which returns the correct drive and location for the current user's profile.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry I completely messed up that backtick formatting... and noticed too late :(